# Recall the current id after form submission

Tags: php, redirect

I have a database where users are allowed to update records via an edit page. After submitting the edits, I'd like the browser to automatically go back to the page they updated to see the results. I thought about using JS to accomplish this:

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo "<script> alert('You have successfully updated.');
            window.location.href='javascript:history.go(-2)';
          </script>";

 }else{
    echo "An error has occurred. Please go back and check the code: ".mysqli_error($con);
 }
```

but this only forces the browser to go back to the page and not a refreshed page with the changes visible. I need to manually refresh the page to see the results this way.

I also tried:

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo "<script> alert('You have successfully updated.');
            window.location.href='01T.php?id=$id';
          </script>";

 }else{
    echo "An error has occurred. Please go back and check the code: ".mysqli_error($con);
 }
```

since 01T.php is the page with the displayed info on it, but that didn't work.

How do I redirect the browser to the same id that was edited to see the results, using a more proper PHP solution?

Comment: You need to send a get request to the `01T.php` page. Something like: `header(Location: 01T.php?userid=10)`;

Comment: Maximus, could I put something in there that looks for the current id number instead? Something like `header(Location: 01T.php?id=$id)`?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.

Comment: In the case that there is more than one page they could be editing from, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the page they arrived from, and if you need to go several pages away, this can be passed to the next page via a GET or POST and you can forward them back to the page afterward with `header('Location: '.$_GET['theUrl'].); exit;`

Comment: I think the problem is that the edit page is willing to POST to the id in question, but not go back to that id page because it doesn't know what it is. I thought that just placing $id in the `Location: 01T.php?id=$id` would work, but it doesn't return the id being edited. When I try this the page url that comes back is `mysite.com/01T.php?id=` ... there's no actual id in the address.

Answer (score 0):

use `header` to redirect

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    header("Location: [url]?id=$id");

 }else{
    echo "An error has occurred. Please go back and check the code: ".mysqli_error($con);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use PHP Sessions to save messages between pages, then when a new page loads check for the presence of a message. If there is one, display it.

In your case, you would save the message if the query was run successfully, then redirect the user.  Then when the new page loads, retrieve that message and show it.

```
<?php
session_start();
...
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    $_SESSION['message'] = "success";
    header("Location: 01T.php?id=$id");
    exit;
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

Then on the every page where you want to show messages:

```
<?php
session_start();
$msgHtml = null; //if it stays null, no message will be shown

//if there is a message. Capture it, then clear it from the session
if(!empty($_SESSION['message'])){
    $message = $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
    //Build the content you want the user to see. Add CSS classes to style it
    $msgHtml = "<div>$message</div>"
}
```

Now, if there is a message for the user, show it. If there is no message, nothing will be output.

In PHP:

```
echo $msgHtml;
```

Or in HTML:

```
<body>
    <?= $msgHtml ?>
</body>
```